# Realm-iOS: Object reference set to nil after save

Tags: ios, realm

I have 2 classes: **Company** and **Employee**. Both inherit the Realm **Object** class.

```
class Company:Object {
    var name:String = ""
    var employee:Employee?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "name"
   }
}

class Employee:Object {
   var name:String = ""
   var age:Int = 0

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "name"
   }
}
```

Populate the objects

```
    var emp = Employee()
    emp.name = "Sachin"
    emp.age = 35

    var comp = Company()
    comp.name = "BCCI"

    comp.employee = emp

    println("Before: \(comp.employee)")

    var realm = Realm()
    realm.write {
        println("Before Add: \(comp.employee)")
        realm.add(comp, update: true)
        println("In Block: \(comp.employee)")
    }

    println("After: \(comp.employee)")
```

**RESULT:**

> Before: Employee {
>       name = Sachin;
>       age = 35;
>       }
>       Before Add: Employee {
>       name = Sachin;
>       age = 35;
>       }
>       In Block: nil
>       After: nil

**QUESTION:**
Why is the employee property of the Company object nil after the `realm.add()` operation? Any thoughts?

Comment: As - in `write`, but before `add`...

Comment: it prints the value in the _write_ block too, it is set to _nil_ just after the _add_

Comment: And lldb says absolutely nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all Realm Swift properties (except for `List`), you need to declare the properties as `dynamic`. Changing your model definitions to the following should help!

```
class Company:Object {
    dynamic var name:String = ""
    dynamic var employee:Employee?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "name"
   }
}

class Employee:Object {
   dynamic var name:String = ""
   dynamic var age:Int = 0

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "name"
   }
}
```