# Swift Realm: After writing transaction reference set to nil

Tags: swift, realm

I have the following code

```
class Family: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    var members = List<FamilyMember>()
}

class FamilyMember: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var belongsToFamily: Family?
}

let realm = try! Realm()

let familyMember = FamilyMember()
familyMember.name = "NameExample"

let newFamily = Family()
newFamily.name = "Familyname"

try! realm.write {
    newFamily.members.append(familyMember)
    familyMember.belongsToFamily = newFamily
    realm.add(newFamily)
    realm.add(familyMember)
}
```

QUESTION: Why is familyMember.belongsToFamily set to nil after Realm's writing transaction?

Comment: I found this article which is close to my problem but still doesn't solve it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118060/realm-ios-object-reference-set-to-nil-after-save

Comment: I used this hint but still don't have a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420889/realm-object-as-member-is-nil-after-saving

Answer (score 1):

It's intended behavior. Realm does not copy any data until actually access the properties. When access the properties, Realm fetch the data directly from its file. So Realm does not store any data to its ivar. Additionally, Realm object will change to another class at the moment it is persisted. That's why you cannot see any values via the debugger and nil out all value after committed.

So if you'd like to debug objects value, you can use `po` command in debug console, or just use `print()` method.

See also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#debugging

> Debugging apps using Realm’s Swift API must be done through the LLDB console.
>
> Note that although the LLDB script installed via our Xcode Plugin allows inspecting the contents of your Realm variables in Xcode’s UI, this doesn’t yet work for Swift. Instead, those variables will show incorrect data. You should instead use LLDB’s po command to inspect the contents of data stored in a Realm.

And see also: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2777

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the line

```
realm.add(newFamily)
```

from your write block?

Comment: Same result.
BUT I've added the following lines to check whether it is nil or not:
                if familyMember?. belongsToFamily! == nil {
                    print("is nil")
                }else{
                    print("is not nil")
                }
The result is: "is not nil" but the debugger shows nil. 
belongsToFamily = (Family?) nil
I am really confused.

Comment: I suggest you install Realm Browser from here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12 or here: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx  and then open your realm file to inspect your data. You can see your data change in the browser when you change it in your code, which makes the Realm Browser a really nice tool. And if you want to open the browser easily I can recommend installing RealmPlugin from Alcatraz.