# Realm Swift returning objects with all nil values

Tags: ios, swift, realm, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using ObjectMapper to parse JSON objects into Realm.

My class Trip looks like this:

```
class Trip: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var Id : String? = nil
    dynamic var CreatedOn : String? = nil
    dynamic var LastModified : String? = nil

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        Id <- map["Id"];
        CreatedOn <- map["CreatedOn"];
        LastModified <- map["LastModified"];
    }
}
```

I am calling a web service request using Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, path, headers: ["Token" : auth_token]).responseJSON { response in

    let dict : NSDictionary? = response.result.value as? NSDictionary

    let test = Mapper<Trip>().map(dict!)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.add(test!)
    try! realm.commitWrite()

    let alltrips : Results<Trip> = realm.objects(Trip)
    let firstTrip = alltrips.first
}
```

In the above code, when I print test, I get:

```
(AwesomeApp.Trip?) test = 0x0000000154e8f0d0 {
  RealmSwift.Object = {
    Realm.RLMObjectBase = {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
    }
  }
  Id = "47d86d34-b6f2-4a9f-9e31-30c81a915492"
  CreatedOn = "2016-01-20T23:39:41.995Z"
  LastModified = "2016-01-20T23:44:39.363Z"
}
```

When I print, firstTrip, I get

```
(AwesomeApp.Trip?) firstTrip = 0x0000000154f1f370 {
  RealmSwift.Object = {
    Realm.RLMObjectBase = {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
    }
  }
  Id = nil
  CreatedOn = nil
  LastModified = nil
}
```

I used the Realm Browser and it looks like the values have been written to the database correctly. However, reading the values returns a trip object with all nil values. Why is this ?

**EDIT**: I printed allTrips using `print (allTrips)` and this printed out:

```
Results<Trip> (
    [0] Trip {
        Id = 47d86d34-b6f2-4a9f-9e31-30c81a915492;
        CreatedOn = 2016-01-20T23:39:41.995Z;
        LastModified = 2016-01-20T23:44:39.363Z;
    }
 )
```

Comment: What's the result of `alltrips`?

Comment: Added the output in the first edit

Comment: I don't see where `first` is coming from in `alltrips.first`...

Comment: Hmm, when I print the value using `print(firstTrip)`, I see the correct result in the console. But when I use the debugger to print the description of either allTrips or firstTrip, I get the nil values

Comment: Try doing `let firstTrip = alltrips[0]`, or `let firstTrip = alltrips?.map {$0}`

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235031/swift-realm-after-writing-transaction-reference-set-to-nil/35265073#35265073) and answers. Using debugger might not be that straightforward while debugging Realm. Take a look at Realm Browser if you don't use it yet.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal I'm facing the same issue, any founded solutions?

Answer (score 3):

The instance variables of a Realm `Object` subclass are only used for objects that have not yet been added to a Realm. After an object has been added to a Realm, or for an object that was retrieved from a Realm, the objects getters and setters access data directly from the Realm without the use of the instance variables. This is why the instance variables do not have the values you expect.

Comment: @RobertTuanVu you saved my ass and time. 

Comment: do you know any way to prevent this returning of nil values ?