# Store data using Realm, add object clears objects on list

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just started to saving data using Realm also using ObjectMapper. The problem I have is:

ObjectInList is inicially with id = 0 and symbol = "CA", after mapping it has different data like id = 0, symbol = "First Name, Last name".

Before `let database` begins I have stored data in profileDictionary variable, and after `database.add(profileDictionary)` **the content of object List changed to initially data** like

`id = 0` and

`symbol = "CA"`

The corious thing is that variable `testInt` didn't change its value and is equal to 10.

Thanks for your advices!

```
class ObjectInList: Object, Mappable{
    dynamic var id : Int = 0
    dynamic var symbol : String = "CA"

    convenience required init?(_ map: Map) {
       self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        symbol <- map["symbol"]
    }
}

class ProfileDictionaries: Object, Mappable{
    dynamic var testInt : Int = 20
    var states = List<ObjectInList>()

    convenience required init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
    // ObjectMapper does not support List<Object>() collections.
        testInt = 10
        var array: [ObjectInList] = []
        array <- map["states"]
        states.appendContentsOf(array)
    }
}

SwiftEventBus.onMainThread(self, name: Constants.ServerResponse.PROFILE_DICTIONARIES_SUCCESS){
  result in

  let profileDictionary  = result.object as? ProfileDictionaries ?? ProfileDictionaries()
   self.removeDatabase()

   do{
       let database = try Realm()
       try! database.write {
       database.add(profileDictionary)
       let localProfileDictionaries = database.objects(ProfileDictionaries)
   }
   catch let error as NSError{
       print(error)
       self.removeDatabase()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post has helped me - [Swift Realm: After writing transaction reference set to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235031/swift-realm-after-writing-transaction-reference-set-to-nil/35268262#35268262)

we should use PO instead of P in LLDB debugger - the data is stored correctly!